# The cause of grayed out in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pycharm

I'm developing Django web apps.

In order to import "settings_common.py" from "settings_dev.py" , I state

```
from .settings_common import *
```

But somehow this statement is grayed out.
[Pycharm capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p475P.png)

I can not figure out why it's grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are not using any of the functions, class or variables from the imported module, they will be grayed out to highlight that you have imported the module but are not using any of it's component in your code.